# Exposing Cognito Protected AWSGateway APIs to clients

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Use-case:
We have a few AWSGateway APIs which our clients can use to do somethings in the backend. These APIs are Cognito protected. Currently our clients are using this APIS through an android app which was built using Cognito Mobile SDKs.

Now we are trying to expose these APIs to our clients to be integrated into their internal workflows.

I was trying to find what is the best way to do this. Currently I am not able to find any resources on how to do this.

I have seem the server side user of AWS Cognito but I don't think that is what we want to do here.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tharun,
Please confirm, for clients integrated into their internal workflows, how authentication will take places,  will it be login window where they will enter username password or will it be client id & secret and it will be service to service communication?

Comment: yes it is service to service communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question correctly we need more information.

- Can the internal workflows be configured to use REST Services?
- What authentication processes does the internal workflows support?

**SDK or no SDK**

You can access the webservices in API Gateway via a generated SDK or your own code.
Instructions to generate an SDK from the API Gateway Console are found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-console.html).

To invoke the webservice with authentication can be done in four ways IAM, API Keys, Cognito, custom authoriser. I am going to mention the first three.

**IAM**

- Step 1, create a user in IAM with an access key and secret key.
- Step 2, is too setup a role to access the API using IAM. Go to
  [IAM](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam), select roles, create a role, and grant it access to your
  API Gateway functions. Which would look something like this:

Sample IAM Policy:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/Alice",
                    "account-id"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage/GET/pets"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

allocate this role to the user you created. Policy examples are available [here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html). For more authentication options that include local certificates etc look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html).

- Step 3, call the API using the AWS Secret and Key [SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-call-api-using-generated-sdk.html).

**API Keys**

If you add keys to your APIs the mobile app will fail as it does not have these keys. It would be best to deploy a different version of your APIs that could wrap the existing ones, could provide additional functionality specific to the workflow. To find out how to do this follow this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html).

The advantage of API keys are that you can throttle access to your API Gateway functions, remove the keys at will, recycle them etc.

**Cognito - Federated Users**

Your mobile users are actually authenticating using [federated users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation.html). However, one of the federated user channels happens to be cognito. You can add more, OpenAuth, Google, Facebook, SAML, etc, here you could add the Authentication type used by your client. A user would then use their username and password, to authenticate to the clients security provider, those credentials are then passed through to the API via federated users, and therefore federated users must be setup to use the same authentication mechanism as your client. See the following [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/secure-api-access-with-amazon-cognito-federated-identities-amazon-cognito-user-pools-and-amazon-api-gateway/)

For this solution we have multiple options. 1. Pass the user credentials through to the API with federated users, this assumes the users interface calls the webservice but as you mentioned it is workflow, and I assume the user does not access the service directly as they do with the mobile application. i.e. services are called by a machine as a background process on a server. Which means this solution will not work. Option 2. is to create a new user, in cognito for the client. This is the same as accessing the service via the mobile app. To do this needs a little work extra work on the client as you need to retrieve the temporary access tokens.

- Step 1. Use the SDK, or code the interface to the API on your own.
- Step 2. Generate a user in Cognito for the backend system to use.
- Step 3. Use the cognito user to obtain access tokens
- Step 4. Use the access tokens to access the webservice in API
  gateway.

**Suggested solution**

Create a second version of your API as a wrapper or extension to your mobile API and use API Keys as described above. Why?

1. Can throttle access to the APIs
2. A different version means you can extend it and add additional functionality specific to workflow
3. Easiest to implement as there is no key exchange, such updates to
   the request header.

**EDIT:** My suggestion of solution 2 is incorrect. AWS Documentation says the [following](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) *To include API methods in a usage plan, you must configure individual API methods to require an API key. For user authentication and authorization, don't use API keys. Use an IAM role, a Lambda authorizer, or an Amazon Cognito user pool.*

AWS Also says the following is available for [controlled access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html)

- **Resource policies** let you create resource-based policies to allow or deny access to your APIs and methods from specified source IP
  addresses or VPC endpoints.
- **Standard AWS IAM** roles and policies offer flexible and robust access controls that can be applied to an entire API or individual
  methods.
- **Cross-origin** resource sharing (CORS) lets you control how your API responds to cross-domain resource requests.
- **Lambda authorizers** are Lambda functions that control access to your API methods using bearer token authentication as well as
  information described by headers, paths, query strings, stage
  variables, or context variables request parameters.
- **Amazon Cognito** user pools let you create customizable authentication and authorization solutions.
- **Client-side SSL** certificates can be used to verify that HTTP requests to your backend system are from API Gateway.
- **Usage plans** let you provide API keys to your customers — and then track and limit usage of your API stages and methods for each API
  key.

Not all the approaches above are intended for authorisation, for example CORS actually protects the user from cross site scripting, and as seen API Keys are only for usage plans. Resource policies just further secure the API by limiting access to IP Addresses, thus your only options really are IAM Roles as described in option 1, and federated users as described in option 3 or your own custom lambda authorize, if you are using Lambda, or your own authorizer if you are using something other than lambda wrapped with API Gateway.

Comment: Hi Jason, I was of the same opinion as you about using the keys, or Cognito Option 2.
But after reading the API Keys section, I think API Keys are just for throttling limits and are not for authentication and authorisation. Even if we use API Keys, I still need to implement Cognitio Option 2 to authenticate the user. Am I wrong?

Comment: Let's say we are using Cognito as the authoriser, what is the standard way of implementing this. Should the implementation of getting the tokens from Cognito be included into the SDK we provide or should we expect the client developer to do it before using our API Gateway generated SDK?

Comment: The client will use their Cognito username and password to perform a key exchange to obtain temporary tokens. They then use these tokens to call the service.

Comment: Here are the docs for .Net but you can find the same for other frameworks, once you have the tokens then call the API Gateway REST Service using the tokens. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/cognito-authentication-extension.html

Comment: In summary - use the AWS SDK to auth the user, passing in the pool data etc, and the username and password. That will give you back a cognito user with a token. See here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html. Then use that info to create an instance of the generated SDK client. ie temp secret, key, token, and region

Comment: Thanks for the details. My question was not clear. Question was should the SDK do all the heavy-lifting as take the username and password from the service and call cognito and add the token to the API request made by the client. Or should the client handle getting the token and adding it to API. What is the standard practice?

Comment: The client accessing your webservices should use the AWS SDK  to authenticate to Cognito, then pass the Cognito credentials received to the generated SDK (API Gateway) or their own rest client to call API Gateway, passing the token, secret and key received from Cognito

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will be service to service or (Server to Server) communication, for this terminology used is Oauth Standard is `client_credentials` grant type.

Please refer the documentation for getting [token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) 
Once the token is acquired,  you need to pass this token either `Authorization` or `API Gateway Custom Header for AWS Cognito`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API Tokens alone for authorization (unless this has been removed recently) 
 I have used them on multiple applications.
This is not recommended for *Authentication* -- but it is application specific if they are sufficient for authorization 
They have been supplemented by more secure methods at the expense of significant complication for both client and server.

API Tokens have the advantage of ease of use for issuer, client and server as they do not require complex signing or protocols -- however they are not as fundamentally secure as they may be reused and generally do not expire as quickly.  Otherwise they are equivalent to bearer tokens.

Security is very context dependant -- consider these question: 
what exactly are you protecting against (providing security *for*) ? What is the risk and cost of a security breach ? What is the cost/effort to implement and use it?
Many security 'holes' are not in the authentication protocol handling itself but rather in how data is managed 'outside the box'  -- No security is perfect, meaning aiming for perfect security has unbounded cost with decreasing effectiveness.  Generally, it is recommended to balance the risk and cost of potential loss vs cost to implement and maintain.
You can have a 'highly secure' API but also have a high risk of breach and data loss due to handling before and after passing through the protected gateway. There are many reasonable cases where instead of focusing on securing the 'front door' with bank vaults and armoured trucks, instead securing the data handling such that no data that is a significant security risk passes through the front door. 
AWS Provides a range of technical features -- but it is ultimately up to each customer to implement them appropriate for their use. API Keys do have a range of appropriate use cases, particularly in server-to-server communications, especially where personal identity (and PI data) is not involved, or where the API involves mainly services instead of data (e.g say a image thumbnail API that stores no state and provides no access to data). When backed by use of HTTPS/SSL and possibly other security factors such as account passphrases, IP range whitelists, and a general policy of least-access.
Don't underestimate the "Sticky Note" factor.  If you make secure access too painful to your users they will find a way to make it less painful, but less secure then simpler measures which they would not have had an incentive to circumvent.